# Travis CI NodeJs build runs locally but gets a permission denied on Travis CI

Tags: javascript, node.js, travis-ci

So when I run locally the mocha test inside my repo It works just fine but when I push a commit and it runs on travis CI I keep getting this error:

```
sh: 1: mocha: Permission denied

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

my `.travis.yml`

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6"

install:
-npm install

before_script: npm install -g mocha
before_script: chmod 0777 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "skeletonapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "skeletonapp",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "li"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

structure of files
[image]

https://travis-ci.org/LiamDotPro/Travis-CI-NodeJS-Skeleton---Mocha-Chai/builds/173340318

test.js

```
var assert = require('assert');
describe('Array', function () {
    describe('#indexOf()', function () {
        it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function () {
            assert.equal(-1, [1, 2, 3].indexOf(4));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on the execute permission on `node_modules/.bin`: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6828#issuecomment-258581083

Or, remove `node_modules` from your Git repository, and let Travis install it with `npm install`. (See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs#Travis-CI-uses-npm.)

Comment: I actually can't thank you enough for taking the time to reply to my issue, Been battling with this for ages. Your the best!

Answer (score 1):

Do not install `mocha` to Travis-CI manually. It's here by default.

Just remove your `before_script`'s statements from the `.travis.yml` file.

Comment: Nicer version added to the main body.

Comment: Can you rerun tests without cache?

Comment: Caching isn't setup for any of the builds